# Get Table Name That Contains A Specific Keyword

Tags: mysql

I have a database named "movie_tags" in my site's phpmyadmin. And I have tables "action, sci-fi, romantic, .... " which containst "id" and "type" columns inside 'movie_tags'.

I am trying to get each table name which contains '57' in it's 'id' column with this code using php and mysql. But it shows "unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'" error

Here is my code

```
SELECT table_name 
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = 'movie_tags' 
   AND id = '57'
```

Comment: There is no column `id` in table `information_schema.tables`. You better rethink the database design, instead of using multiple tables for each genre, you may use a column like `genre` and filter from it.

Comment: Alternative is to use `UNION` clause `select * from action where id = 57 union all select * from romantic where id = 57 union all ...`

Comment: I think if you find yourself regularly hitting the information_schema, it's probably time to reconsider your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do Like This

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($your_connection_to_db, "SHOW TABLES FROM movie_tags");

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $query2 = mysqli_query($your_connection_to_db, "SELECT * FROM `".$array[0]."` WHERE id = '57'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

    if($rows>0){
        //you can do your code here with $array[0]. Example
        echo "your ".$array[0]." table has 57 in it's id column";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot. This Works For Me As My Wish

Comment: Your Welcome. Pleasure To Help